# C# Rest API returns null when I post

Tags: c#, rest, postman

I'm pretty new to C# and rest programming and have a very basic question:
This is my Rest Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/LOP")]
public class T7_controller : ApiController

{

    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string temp)
    {
        return temp;
    }

}
}
```

and when I post on it via Postman it doesn't return my desired value but null.
This is my JSON:

```json
{
    "temp": "test"
}
```

I changed postman to post and the contenttype is on application/json

Can anybody help me?

Comment: have you changed your body type to raw->json?

Comment: jeeven ebi Yes i did

Comment: can you please share the request URL?

Comment: Parameter binding works a lil bit different. [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) If you want just the string you should be fine with posting just it without the json object around it (like in the example)

Comment: jeeven ebi thats just 127.0.0.1:58930/api/lop/test

Comment: Hey pio thanks for your answer, i read that but i am not complete sure now, soe do i just have to give a json object when i want to have multiple parameters in my endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the refactored code

```
[Route("api/LOP")]
[ApiController]
public class T7_controller : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] string temp)
    {
        return temp;
    }
}


 Http Method :  POST 
 Request : YOURHOST/api/LOP/Test
 Payload : "Test"
```

**Response : Test**

Please note that sending a single string value as a JSON payload might seem unusual because JSON is typically used to represent more complex data structures (objects, arrays, etc.). If you intend to send a more structured JSON payload, you might want to define a custom class to model the data and use that class as the parameter type for your controller action. This will allow you to work with more structured and meaningful data in your API.